# Form behavior posting nested resource

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, post, redirect

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to change its conventional behavior on posting a form in order to post from a `signup` action to the `create` action instead that from the `new` action. That is, I would like to use the `signup` action instead of the (conventional) `new` action in my `User` controller and trigger the `create` action to save my model data that contains nested resources.

In my `/config/routes.rb` file I have:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get  'signup'
  end

  resource :profile
end
```

In my `/app/controllers/users_controller.rb` I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def signup
    @signup_user = User.new(params[:user])
    @signup_user.build_profile # NOTE: Nested resource
    ...
  end

  def create
    ...
    @signup_user.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => :signup } # signup.html.erb
end
  end
end
```

In my `/app/views/users/signup.html.erb` file I have

```
<%= form_for @signup_user do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

*My problem is that if I submit the above form, I will be redirected to the `index` action of the user controller and not to the `create` action I expect.* It seams that the form posts only to the `index` action.

**How can I solve the problem?**

---

I tryed to use the following

```
<%= form_for( :user, @signup_user, :url => { :controller => "users", :action => "create" }, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>
```

but I have still the problem: I am redirected to the `index` action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **SOLUTION**

The problem did seam to be in the `routers.rb`. The correct code was

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get  'signup'
    post 'create'
  end

  resource :profile
end
```